# How to pick minimal buffer size for number to string converting?

Tags: c++

I try to make minimal buffer for `std::snprintf` to convert `uint64_t` to `std::string` and found error in converted string for big values

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

// assume this is maximum string size to represent any unsigned integer
// with 1 extra byte for string terminating null character
const std::size_t MAX_UINT64_WIDTH = 
        std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::digits10 + 1;

int main(int, char**)
{
    uint64_t          value  = 10244450920698242790ULL;
    const std::string svalue = "10244450920698242790";

    std::string str;
    char buf[MAX_UINT64_WIDTH];
    auto l = std::snprintf(buf, MAX_UINT64_WIDTH, "%" PRIu64, value);
    if (l > 0) {
        str.assign(buf, buf + l);
    }
    assert(svalue == str); //assertion failed, the last character '0' (0x30) is replaced with '\0' (0x00)
    return 0;
}
```

Then I found that `assert(21 == MAX_UINT64_WIDTH);` also fails. And finally minimal program shows up error is

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::to_string(std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()).size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

user@host:~$ g++ --std=c++11 -o check check.cpp 
user@host:~$ ./check 
18446744073709551615
19
20


user@host:~$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)
```

**Update**
I misuse library `digits10` so I rename my question.

Comment: Your character buffer needs to be the maximum length *plus one*, to hold the terminating null character.

Comment: Yes, so I take `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::digits10 + 1`, but standard library gives `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::digits10` == 19 instead of 20.

Comment: digits10 does not do what you think it does. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) is the number of digits of a number that you can "safely" store in that type. If for example `std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()` is `18446744073709551615` then you cannot store a number with same number of digits and all digits equal to 9 in an `uint64_t`.

Lets say, if the `max` has `N` digits, then `digits10` is typically `N-1` (unless `max` is 99999...9999).